# Combine multiple Data Frames with WHILE loop

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop

[Screenshot of results from Updated code from suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAvna.png)

'dlist' is a list of provider id that is in a dataframe. I tried to use a while loop for 'dlist', but it only returns the value of the last provider id in the array. In this case it is 1005. I used the append function but it didn't do anything. The additional 74 rows from provider id 1000 are not showing. How do I combine everything so it shows the values of both numbers from dlist, to equal 684 rows?

```
dlist = ["1000", "1005"]

final_list = pd.DataFrame()

index = 0

while index < len(dlist):
    provider = dlist[index]
    
    # Filter dentist (CHANGEABLE)
    final_list = report_df[(report_df["provider_id"] == provider)]

    # Sort values of the codes
    final_list = final_list.sort_values(['codes','report_month'], ascending=True)

    # Drop 'report_year' column
    final_list = final_list.drop(['report_year'], axis = 1)

    # Change 'report_month' numbers into month name
    final_list = final_list.replace({'report_month': {1: "January",
                                                      2: "February",
                                                      3: "March",
                                                      4: "April",
                                                      5: "May",
                                                      6: "June",
                                                      7: "July",
                                                      8: "August",
                                                      9: "September",
                                                      10: "October",
                                                      11: "November"}})
    final_list.append(final_list)
    index +=1
```

[Missing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV3cK.png)

[Result of the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5jSH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list with all the dataframes and then concatenate them.
Like before the while loop have a list of dataframes.

```
list_of_dfs = []
```

And prior to the `index+=1` add the `final_list` to list of dataframes.

```
list_of_dfs.append(final_list)
```

You probably dont want to append like `final_list.append(final_list)`.

Eventually, you could do

```
my_df_of_concern = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, index=0)
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: I added the ist_of_dfs = [] and list_of_dfs.append(final_list). I will be posting a photo of the results. It is closer to what I wanted it to be but it shows the dataframes in a list? Where do I add "my_df_of_concern = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, index=0)"?

Comment: Add `my_df_of_concern = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, index=0)` after the while loop, . not indented in the loop

Comment: I reran everything and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are modifying the same variable again and again. In your code:

```
Line 1: while index < len(dlist):
Line 2:    provider = dlist[index]
    
Line 3:    # Filter dentist (CHANGEABLE)
Line 4:    final_list = report_df[(report_df["provider_id"] == provider)] # PROBLEM LINE
Line 5:    # MORE CODE
Line 6:    # MORE CODE
Line 7:    final_list.append(final_list)
Line 8:    index +=1
```

Since your `dlist` has `["1000", "1005"]`, during the first run, in line 4, `final_list` has all the rows where `provider_id == 1000`. Then you make some modifications to it and then in Line 7, you append it to the same object. So now, final_list is going to have 2 copies of everything because you are doing `final_list.append(final_list)`

Then you increment index and for the next iteration where provider is now `1005`, you again do Line 4 where by your final_list is going to be overwritten. This means that all your previous values stored in that variable is no longer present only the new values where `provider_id == 1005` is present.

Try changing your code like this

```
while index < len(dlist):
    provider = dlist[index]
    
    # Filter dentist (CHANGEABLE)
    report_list = report_df[(report_df["provider_id"] == provider)]

    # Sort values of the codes
    report_list = report_list.sort_values(['codes','report_month'], ascending=True)

    # Drop 'report_year' column
    report_list = report_list.drop(['report_year'], axis = 1)

    # Change 'report_month' numbers into month name
    report_list = report_list.replace({'report_month': {1: "January",
                                                      2: "February",
                                                      3: "March",
                                                      4: "April",
                                                      5: "May",
                                                      6: "June",
                                                      7: "July",
                                                      8: "August",
                                                      9: "September",
                                                      10: "October",
                                                      11: "November"}})
    final_list.append(report_list)
    index +=1
```

`report_list` acts as a temporary variable which holds all the data of a particular provider and then after all your modifications like dropping report_year column, sorting, etc. you append the values to final_list. Now you will have the data across multiple iterations.

Also, instead of doing

```
while index < len(dlist):
    provider = dlist[index]
    index +=1
```

you can do this:

```
for provider in dlist:
    # YOUR CODE where provider will be "1000" for 1st run and "1005" in second run
```

Comment: So i updated the code to:

Comment: So i updated the code. Now it says the list index is out of range. Initialized provider = 0.                                                                                            for provider in dlist:
    # Filter dentist
    report_list = report_df[(report_df["provider_id"] == dlist[provider])]

Comment: when you run `for provider in dlist`, the value of provider is going to be 1000 for the first run and then 1005 for the second run. You should use dlist[provider]. Just change it to `report_df["provider_id"] == provider`